# How to set hibernate/shutdown timers? XFCE power manager not having an effect in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate

I like to fall asleep listening to internet radio or a streaming video. I would prefer to have my computer go into hibernate mode an hour after I've become inactive, not 15 minutes after.

I would then like my computer to shut-down if I don't touch it a half-hour after that.

But I cannot change the hibernate or shut down settings.

This is an Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

On the Xfce Power Manager, I have the monitor at "put display to sleep when computer is inactive for 60 minuts" but it goes black when inactive for only 15 minutes.

And "put computer to sleep when inactive for" is set for 1 hour 58 minutes. But it just stays on with a dark screen.

I'm not a programmer, technology person at all. A friend convinced me to try Linux, saying lubuntu was the most user-friendly version.

Thanks

Comment: Do you realise you are talking about 4 different things - screen going off, sleep, hibernate, and shutdown.  Screen going off is not sleep mode.  Sleep mode is not hibernate.

Comment: Also, lubuntu is not the most user-friendly version, it's probably the least user-friendly of the full graphical desktops.  And XFCE and Lubuntu are two separate desktops: the XFCE power manager may or may not work on a Lubuntu install.

Comment: @neon_overload - XFCE power manager is included by default in Lubuntu and manages some power settings.

Comment: Fine. So, how can I set my screen to go off after an hour and the laptop to shut-down after 2 hours of inactivity?

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off Light Locker. You can find it in Preferences > Light Locker Settings. Turn the "Enable light-locker" to Off. This may be what is turning off your screen after 10-15 minutes.

Are you using a laptop or desktop? If you are using a laptop, please note that there are different settings for battery power or plugged-in.

Also make sure in the "Display" section of Xfce Power Manager you have the Screen set to blank never.

I do not believe you can set the computer to shutdown after a period of inactivity using Xfce Power Manager.

I can recommend a way to schedule shutdown for a certain time everyday:

For a one-time shutdown, go into the terminal (press CTRL + Alt + T or open Accessories > LXTerminal) and enter this command:

```
sudo shutdown -h 03:30
```

(Replace 03:30 with your desired time in 24:00 format)

If you would want your computer to turn off at a certain time every day, you could enter this command in LXTerminal (press CTRL + Alt + T or open Accessories > LXTerminal):

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Which might say it is creating a file and might offer the choice of text editor. (If you get to choose, I'd recommend "nano").

In nano, press the down button to go to the last line in the document and enter this line:

```
30 3 * * * poweroff
```

Replace 3 with the hour and 30 with the # of minutes past the hour you would like the system to shut down. (Note: The spacing between the numbers, asterisks, and command is important here.)

Once you've entered this command, press (CTRL + X) to exit nano, and enter Y to save the new file.

Please let me know if you have questions or would like some clarification.

Comment: Thanks drkokandy. I've done what you said and I'll see what happens. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I had just the same request, and wanted it in friendly way so started  xfce panel plugin development to address this problem. It is still in development stage.
You may find the plugin here https://gitlab.xfce.org/szasenko/xfce4-powertimer-plugin/